# "pip install super_gradients" results in " error: subprocess-exited-with-error"

Tags: python

When running this command in jupyter notebook

```
pip install super_gradients
```

It returns this error:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Please check the error logs for more details about the error. Those lines you posted are just the generic end of most "pip install" error logs, and there is usually more details before that on what went wrong and what the _actual_ error is. Please [edit] your question with more parts of the error.

Comment: Please also [edit] to specify your Python and OS version